# Переделать ArrayList в коде под обычный массив

Tags: java

Вечер добрый господа, вопрос в том, как переделать мне мой код чтобы в нем вообще не встречался ArrayList вообще, а вместо него использовать обычный массив.

```
public class Callboard {
    private ArrayList<Author> authors;
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;

    public Callboard() {
        authors = new ArrayList<>();
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /* --Метод SaveMassage сохраняет отправленное сообщение и возвращает true обратно если пользователь был ранее зарегистрирован,
        если нет, то метод не сохраняет сообщение и возвращает false; */

    public boolean SaveMassage(Message message) {
        if (message == null) return false;
        for (Author _author : authors) {
            if (_author.getName().equals(message.getAuthor().getName())) {
                messages.add(message);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* --Метод regUser сохраняет отправленного пользователя и возвращает true, если ни один другой пользователь с подобным именем
        не был зарегистрирован до этого. В противном случае метод не сохраняет пользователя и возвращает false. */

    public boolean regUser(Author author) {
        if (author == null) return false;
        for (Author _author : authors) {
            if (_author.getName().equals(author.getName())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        authors.add(author);
        return true;
    }

    /* -- Метод findUser ищет пользователя с заданным именем зарегистрированного ранее" на доске обьявлений" и возвращает этого пользователя.
        Если пользователь с таким именем не существует, то метод возвращает null обратно. */
    public Author findUser(String name) {
        if (name.length() < 1) return null;
        for (Author _author : authors) {
            if (_author.getName().equals(name)) {
                return _author;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* -- Метод findMassages для поиска сообщений. Этот метод возвращает массив хранимых сообщений, чья тема или сообщение содержит
        переданную строку поиска (в качестве подстроки)(полу-String). Написание с большой или маленькой буквы должно быть проигнориванно.
        Если ни одно сообщение не удовлетворяет ранее упомянотому критерию, то метод должен вернуть пустой массив(не null)(Просто пустой массив). */

    public ArrayList<Message> findMassages(String str) {
        ArrayList<Message> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            if (message.getTheme().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())){
                result.add(message);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /* -Методы возвращают количество сообщений соответственно зарегистрированных пользователей. */

    public int СMassages(){
        return messages.size();
    }
    public int CAutors(){
        return authors.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, перестаньте ДУБЛИРОВАТЬ КОД и придерживайтесь правил именования переменных и методов!!! В остальном реализация может быть примерно такая (хотя это хуже, чем использование коллекции и я не знаю, зачем это вам):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Callboard {

    private Author[] authors;
    private Message[] messages;

    public Callboard() {
        authors = new Author[0];
        messages = new Message[0];
    }

    /* --Метод SaveMassage сохраняет отправленное сообщение и возвращает true обратно если пользователь был ранее зарегистрирован,
        если нет, то метод не сохраняет сообщение и возвращает false; */
    public boolean saveMassage(Message message) {
        return message == null || message.getAuthor() == null || findUser(message.getAuthor().getName()) == null 
                ? false : addElementToArray(messages, message);
    }

    /* --Метод regUser сохраняет отправленного пользователя и возвращает true, если ни один другой пользователь с подобным именем
        не был зарегистрирован до этого. В противном случае метод не сохраняет пользователя и возвращает false. */
    public boolean regUser(Author author) {
        return author == null || findUser(author.getName()) == null 
                ? false : addElementToArray(authors, author);
    }

    /* -- Метод findUser ищет пользователя с заданным именем зарегистрированного ранее" на доске обьявлений" и возвращает этого пользователя.
        Если пользователь с таким именем не существует, то метод возвращает null обратно. */
    public Author findUser(String name) {
        return name==null ? null : Arrays.stream(authors)
                .filter(author -> author.getName().equals(name))
                .findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    /* -- Метод findMassages для поиска сообщений. Этот метод возвращает массив хранимых сообщений, чья тема или сообщение содержит
        переданную строку поиска (в качестве подстроки)(полу-String). Написание с большой или маленькой буквы должно быть проигнориванно.
        Если ни одно сообщение не удовлетворяет ранее упомянотому критерию, то метод должен вернуть пустой массив(не null)(Просто пустой массив). */
    public Message[] findMassages(final String str) {
        return Arrays.stream(messages)
                .filter(message -> message.getTheme().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()))
                .toArray(Message[]::new);
    }

    /* -Методы возвращают количество сообщений соответственно зарегистрированных пользователей. */
    public int cMassages() {
        return messages.length;
    }

    public int cAutors() {
        return authors.length;
    }

    private <T> boolean addElementToArray(T [] array, T t){
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
        array[array.length - 1] = t;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Простите Дмитрий, а возможно ли было без вообще каких либо методов типа import java.util.Arrays переписать код? С методами не хотят принимать, поэтому и попросил чтобы без ArrayList помогли написать :(

Comment: @Str можно, здесь Arrays - либо точка входа в стрим для масисва, а это по сути легко поменять на обычный цикл, либо вызов копирования, тут тоже по сути можно создать новый массив и скопировать в цикле, но тогда вы еще больше проиграете в производительности, потому как Arrays.copyOf - достаточно быстрый метод в силу нативных вызовов. я только не могу понять, чт о это за больная фантазия такая? import java.util.Arrays  - это не метод, это импорт класса из пакета  java.util. ровно такого же класса, как, например String, которым вы пользуетесь, просто классы из пакета lang импортировать не надо

Comment: С этим, к сожалению, ничего поделать не могу, такая вот фантазия у преподов сегодня )

Comment: К сожалению методы работаю неправильно....

Comment: @Str код я исправил,  пробуйте еще раз. в любом случае то, что вы предоставили, - лишь часть кода. я не могу его запустить, я не знаю желаемого поведения, вы не дали тестов либо тесткейсов и т.д. при таких условиях дебаг - ваша задача. в любом случае я всего лишь пытаюсь помочь найти этот ответ, а не решить задачу за вас. в противном случае хотя бы описывайте , что именно  отработало некорректно. фраза "работает неправильно" имеет значение только для экстрасенсов.

Comment: Да, вы правы...Спасибо.. Попробую протестировать и если получится, то загружу в чем ошибка)

Comment: @Str в любом случае баг я точно нашел и исправил. вопрос в том, один ли он... пишите о результатах

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но почему-то проблема осталась таже, а именно не считает ни пользователей, ни сообщения. Регистрация пользователей и метод сообщений работают неправильно( к сожалению(

Comment: @Str мне о вашей проблеме известно ровно столько же,сколько вам известно о моих. ваша задача звучала так : переделать ArrayList в коде под обычный массив.надо переделать-я переделал.то,что ваш код изначально горбатый и то,что у вас есть еще гора каких-то странных условий(типа запрета на использование любых импортов),не является предметом вопроса. необходимо тестирование-пишите и проводите, необходима отладка - такая же история. другой вопрос,когда вы не понимаете, почему при конкретном тестовом случае метод выдает определенный конкретный результат. просто угадать, что вы хотите, не получится))

Comment: Да в том и дело, что с аррау листом работает все, но тест не проходит только из-за того, что метод findMassages должен возвращать массив и так как  не знаю, как переделать аррау.лист чтобы он возвращал массив, я и попросил как можно было бы переделать его в что-то другое. Условия уже изменились и препод дал зеленый свет на все) На счет кода, то да, но увы сюда нельзя загрузить 3 класса с джава чтобы кто-то посмотрел( Да, увы, пробую, но не понимаю почему не работает, опыта мало

Comment: @Str из ArrayList в массив достаточно просто: result.toArray(new Message[result.size()])